# What model is this Specialized bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]

This is an older Specialized MTB bike, I want to know the name of the frame so I can research the repairs.

Comment: You almost certainly don't need to know the model name to repair the bike.

Comment: The bike uses reasonably generic components.  You do not need to know the specific model to obtain parts.

Comment: If you really want to know the model, please add a clear picture from the drive side. and a close up picture of the crank/chainrings and rear derailleur.

Comment: Another option is to check the serial number with specialized CSR team.    At least they're still in business.

Comment: What "repairs" are needed?  It appears to be in pretty good shape (though it's hard to say for sure given the poor quality picture).

Comment: The model is written on the top tube. It's a Hardrock. But you'd need the serial number to know which specific Hardrock and which specific year.

Comment: Colour photo would help. Head over to bikepedia.com and look though, Spec. Hardrock. My guess is early 2000 or late 1990's  (V Brakes and 1 1/8" steerer) https://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2000&brand=Specialized%20&model=Hardrock

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know - its not a great photo.  But we can see its got QRs and rim brakes, no suspension and what look like rotary or grip shifters.

There's a threadless steerer though, so its not a quill stem which would be a BSO grade (ie super cheap)

So you're looking at a low-end model from the late 90s I think.   Possibly early 2000s.

Your best bet is to dig through a google image search of specialised hybrid/commuter bike frames and look for a match.  Its quite tedious.  Or https://www.bikepedia.com/Year.aspx?search=specialized